# Sort function isn't working

Tags: excel, vba

I have a dynamic range `rng2` that goes from `A4:F?`. I tried adapting code from this site, but keep getting errors when I try to sort it. `Officers` is a string `"E1:E" & last row`. `Tgroup` is a string `"D1:D" & last row`.

```
rng2.Sort key1:=Range(officers), Order1:=xlAscending, _
key2:=Range(tgroup), order2:=x1Ascending, Header:=x1No
```

---

From comments:

`i` is a counter used earlier & is 1 row below the last row.

```
Dim officers As String, tgroup As String, sArea As String, rng2 As Range
officers = "E1:E" & (i - 4)
tgroup = "D1:D" & (i - 4)
sArea = "A4:F" & (i - 1)
Set rng2 = rng.Range(sArea)
rng2.Sort key1:=Range(officers), Order1:=xlAscending, _ 
          key2:=Range(tgroup), order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
```

`rng` is a range from `A1:F?` but has merged cells which is why I have `rng2`.

Comment: Can you please include enough code to show how `rng2`, `officers` and `tgroup` are set.  (And probably how `last row`(?) is set.)

Comment: "Isn't working" Is not an error description. What are your errors?

Comment: You got typos in `order2:=x1Ascending` and `Header:=x1No` there is a one `1` in it but it should be a lower case `L` like `xlAscending` and also `xlNo`.

Comment: The error is: Run-time error '1004': The sort reference is not valid. make sure that it's within the data you want to sort, and the first Sort By box isn't the same or blank.

Comment: @YowE3k here is the leading code.i is a counter used earlier & is 1 row below the last row.

Dim officers As String, tgroup As String, sArea As String, rng2 As Range
 officers = "E1:E" & (i - 4)
 tgroup = "D1:D" & (i - 4)
 sArea = "A4:F" & (i - 1)
 Set rng2 = rng.Range(sArea)
 rng2.Sort key1:=Range(officers), Order1:=xlAscending, _
     key2:=Range(tgroup), order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo

rng is a range from A1:F? but has merged cells which is why I have rng2.

Comment: So, assuming `i` is 20, you are trying to sort the cells in `A4:F19` using keys in `E1:E16` and `D1:D16`.  You really need to have your keys within the data that you want to sort.  (I apologise that I didn't even notice that you had mentioned those ranges in your original question.)

Comment: @YowE3K 
When you create a range isn't the first cell considered A1. If so then with i=20 rng2 would be A1:F16.

Comment: I was reading `rng` as a worksheet object.  Where have you set `rng`?  (I might be missing it in the code in the comment - you should really use the "edit" button below your question and place extra information that helps to solve your problem into the question itself - much easier to read there!)

Comment: @YowE3K Thanks. I'm new to this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data you want to sort (without headings) starts in row 4 of the `ActiveSheet`, change your definitions of `officers` and `tgroup` to be:

```
officers = "E4:E" & (i - 1)
tgroup = "D4:D" & (i - 1)
sArea = "A4:F" & (i - 1)
'and probably best to set the sort area based on the sheet itself
'to be consistent with how you have defined the keys
Set rng2 = Range(sArea)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason the sort didn't work correctly isn't as @YowE3k suggested. The answer is that I wasn't accurately defining the range portion of the sort. The solution is:

```
    rng2.Sort key1:=rng2.Range(officers), Order1:=xlAscending, _
        key2:=rng2.Range(tgroup), order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
```

I wasn't using the rng2.Range so it was getting the wrong area & couldn't sort.